# Large data processing in x86 C# gives System.OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I am processing XML coming from server which contains both images and data in one C# function (compiled 32 bit).
 When I try to parse this xml in memory it gives me System.OutOfMemory exception.

Is there any way to avoid this error?

My guess is, system cannot find contiguous block of 50-100MB memory. (my pc hv 8Gig ram and its quad core)

Comment: Are you saying the XML files are 50-100mb each? What XML parser are you using? Post your code

Comment: You say this is a server app - how many concurrent xml docs are you parsing ? Maybe you can limit how many inbound requests get processed concurrently on the server ?

Comment: @Michael, I am getting one XElement at a time which I get using following code-
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(xelement.Value.ToString());
Then from this output, I process each node individually.
         @Romain, I process only one xml doc at a time.

Comment: Please post *all* your code--not just one line :)

Answer (score 2):

An XML file that is 50-100 MB on disk is going to be a *lot* larger when parsed into a DOM. (Assuming of course that you're using XmlDocument or XDocument.)

Although I despise the API, you may want to look into using XmlReader to "stream" the document in. It will be much more performant than using the DOM but it's a lot less intuitive to use.